# HTML5 Canvas - space appears from where?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a  inside of a canvas div and it is occupying too much space. I don't know how I should fix it.
so there is the canvas occupying 600x250, and the div occupying another 600x250.
I've added a screenshot so you can see what I'm talking about:
[click!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3QoJ.png)

Am I missing something? I'm new to canvas btw. Just tried to do this thing so I learn something new :D

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var canvasx = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = canvasx.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasx.offsetHeight;

    
    var x1 = 85;
    var x2 = 150;
    var x3 = 245;
    var x4 = 350;
    var x5 = 430;
    var x6 = 520; 
    var y1 = 0;
    var x = 300;
    var y = 50;
    var dy = 2;
    var dy1 = 2
    var friction = 0.85;
    var gravity = 0.8;

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillText("Front-End Developing", x, y1);
        ctx.fillText("✓ HTML", x1, y);
        ctx.font = "bold 20px Roboto Condensed";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#77dff1";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillText("✓ CSS", x2, y);
        ctx.fillText("✓ JavaScript", x3, y);
        ctx.fillText("✓ Canvas", x4, y);
        ctx.fillText("✓ jQuery", x5, y);
        ctx.fillText("✓ Bootstrap", x6, y);  
        if (y + 50 > canvas.height) {
            dy = -dy * friction;
        }
        else {
            dy += gravity;
        }
        if (y1 - 100 > canvas.height) {
            dy1 = -dy1 * friction;
        }
        else {
            dy1 += gravity;
        }

        y1 += dy;
        y += dy;
    }

    animate();
});
```

```css
#central-skills {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1300px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    user-select: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

#canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.canvas {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 55%;
}

.trying {
    text-align: center;
}

#website ul {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#websites li:before {
    content: "\2714\0020";
}

#websites {

    font-size: 0 !important;
}

.websites {
    text-align: center;

}

#websites ul {

}

#websites li {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.list-adv {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #77dff1;
    padding: 6rem;
    margin: 0;
    color: #77dff1;
}

.scratch {

}

.mobile-skills {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#icons {
    font-size: 10rem;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 6vw;
}

.fa-html5 {

}

.fa-js-square {

}

.fa-css3-alt {

}
```

```html
<div id="central-skills">
            <h6 class="trying">Currently I consider myself familiar and comfortable with:</h6>
            <h6 class="mobile-skills">html CSS JavaScript jQuery Bootstrap Canvas</h6>
            <div id="canvas">
                <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
                <script src="js/canvas.js"></script>
            </div>                
                <div id="icons">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="html"><i class="fab fa-html5"></i></li>
                        <li id="js"><i class="fab fa-js-square"></i></li>
                        <li id="css"><i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="websites"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li class="list-adv 1">Responsive</li>
                        <li class="list-adv 2">Using a clean and easy to follow code</li>
                        <li class="list-adv 3">Clean and good-looking</li>
                        <li class="list-adv 4">Optimized for Search Engines (SEO)</li>
                        <li class="list-adv scratch">Coded from scratch (unless there is a need of a CMS)</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You're not doing anything to make the canvas smaller. Think of canvas like an image. An image has a natural height and width but can also be scaled with CSS. By default a canvas is 300x150px. If you set the size with CSS you will scale whatever is on the canvas but the canvas will still be 300x150. If you want to change the actual size of the canvas you have to do it with it's width and height attributes. You should start off by reading [the tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial).

Comment: Yes, but the <canvas> appears separately as another 600x250. The divs takes other 600x250. How can I fix it?

Comment: Oohh.. i see what you mean now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the canvas to be 55% lower than it should be.. this is why your actual canvas is rendered lower than it's parent div. Remove the `.canvas` stuff from the CSS and it will appear inside it's parent div again.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var canvasx = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = canvasx.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasx.offsetHeight;

    
    var x1 = 85;
    var x2 = 150;
    var x3 = 245;
    var x4 = 350;
    var x5 = 430;
    var x6 = 520; 
    var y1 = 0;
    var x = 300;
    var y = 50;
    var dy = 2;
    var dy1 = 2
    var friction = 0.85;
    var gravity = 0.8;

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillText("Front-End Developing", x, y1);
        ctx.fillText("✓ HTML", x1, y);
        ctx.font = "bold 20px Roboto Condensed";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#77dff1";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillText("✓ CSS", x2, y);
        ctx.fillText("✓ JavaScript", x3, y);
        ctx.fillText("✓ Canvas", x4, y);
        ctx.fillText("✓ jQuery", x5, y);
        ctx.fillText("✓ Bootstrap", x6, y);  
        if (y + 50 > canvas.height) {
            dy = -dy * friction;
        }
        else {
            dy += gravity;
        }
        if (y1 - 100 > canvas.height) {
            dy1 = -dy1 * friction;
        }
        else {
            dy1 += gravity;
        }

        y1 += dy;
        y += dy;
    }

    animate();
});
```

```css
#central-skills {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1300px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    user-select: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

#canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

/**
You're setting the canvas to be 55% lower than it should be.. this is why you're having trouble. I don't why this is here in the first place but removing it will fix the problem.

.canvas {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 55%;
}
*/

.trying {
    text-align: center;
}

#website ul {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#websites li:before {
    content: "\2714\0020";
}

#websites {

    font-size: 0 !important;
}

.websites {
    text-align: center;

}

#websites ul {

}

#websites li {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.list-adv {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #77dff1;
    padding: 6rem;
    margin: 0;
    color: #77dff1;
}

.scratch {

}

.mobile-skills {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#icons {
    font-size: 10rem;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 6vw;
}

.fa-html5 {

}

.fa-js-square {

}

.fa-css3-alt {

}
```

```html
<div id="central-skills">
            <h6 class="trying">Currently I consider myself familiar and comfortable with:</h6>
            <h6 class="mobile-skills">html CSS JavaScript jQuery Bootstrap Canvas</h6>
            <div id="canvas">
                <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
                <script src="js/canvas.js"></script>
            </div>                
                <div id="icons">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="html"><i class="fab fa-html5"></i></li>
                        <li id="js"><i class="fab fa-js-square"></i></li>
                        <li id="css"><i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="websites"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li class="list-adv 1">Responsive</li>
                        <li class="list-adv 2">Using a clean and easy to follow code</li>
                        <li class="list-adv 3">Clean and good-looking</li>
                        <li class="list-adv 4">Optimized for Search Engines (SEO)</li>
                        <li class="list-adv scratch">Coded from scratch (unless there is a need of a CMS)</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Yeah. I forgot to delete that when I've cleared things. I didn't realise it was still there. Thanks a lot. By the way, can you help me make the text like in this image? https://imgur.com/a/kKgRc if I position it higher on canvas the bouncing effect will not be visible anymore.

Comment: @OctavianNiculescu - The animation effect is a great exercise for learning canvas but to be honest this is not really a relisting implementation of it. For something like this you wouldn't use a canvas, you'd just animate the DOM. If you really want to use a canvas though, you can just draw the text on the canvas itself.. I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: You didn't. It's still the same.